# Cmake error when I create an new NDK project with androidstudio

Tags: android, android-ndk

AndroidStudio 3.1.4

NDK 17.2.4988734 ,r16b

cmake 3.6.4111459

I try to create an new Project with include C++ support.But the project is always build failed.

```
Build command failed.


Error while executing process D:\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {-HE:\workspace\android-ndk-master\Makeup\app -BE:\workspace\android-ndk-master\Makeup\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-24 -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=E:\workspace\android-ndk-master\Makeup\app\build\intermediates\cmake\release\obj\armeabi-v7a -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DANDROID_NDK=D:\Android\Sdk\androidndkr16b -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS= -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:\Android\Sdk\androidndkr16b\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=D:\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja}


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!


 Parse error.  Expected a command name, got unquoted argument with text "b". 
Open File


Build command failed.


Error while executing process D:\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {-HE:\workspace\android-ndk-master\Makeup\app -BE:\workspace\android-ndk-master\Makeup\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-24 -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=E:\workspace\android-ndk-master\Makeup\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DANDROID_NDK=D:\Android\Sdk\androidndkr16b -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS= -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:\Android\Sdk\androidndkr16b\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=D:\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja}


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!


 Parse error.  Expected a command name, got unquoted argument with text "b". 
Open File
```

Comment: may you follow this one to see if you get the same:  https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-studio-cmake/index.html#0 . ?   Probably create a project within a new directory.

Comment: The problem has been solved.The global encryption software cause it.

Comment: Oh , great it is solved!  wondering if you could add yours as "Answers", so this will not coming up when searching for unanswered questions. "nice to have" thing, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved.The global encryption software cause it.